# Symfony2 route is not working

Tags: symfony, routes

I created a new symfony project, but the routing is not working at all. 
This is my `routing.yml` file:

```
app:
resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation
```

And this is part of my controller:

```
    class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
        ));
    }
```

After this I've created some test functions with the associated route, but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: *"...but it doesn't work."* Please explain **how** it does not work. Currently your question is unanswerable.

Comment: This is what I get: NOT FOUND, The requested URL /project/test was not found on this server.

Comment: Ok, there's tons of possible reasons for this. First, always develop with `app_dev.php` in your url, this way you'll get better error messages. Second: Is your sf app actually *rooted* in `/project/test`? Third, to debug your routes, you can use: `php app/console debug:router` (for sf2) to see all configured routes (with path templates).

Comment: My app is rooted in `localhost:8888/project`.  `project/test` is a route of an action I've defined and that appears in the result of the command `php app/console debug:router`

Comment: Then your test url should be `project/project/test` (probably).

Comment: same error, URL NOT FOUND

Comment: Is `localhost:8888/project` pointing to the `web` directory inside your sf app? If not, then the url might actually be: `localhost:8888/project/web/project/test` (and to debug: `localhost:8888/project/web/app_dev.php/project/test`)

Comment: Ok, I tried `localhost:8888/project/web/test` and now it works! Now I have to understand why :) Thnx!

Comment: You need to point the domain (+path) you want to use, to the `web` directory inside the sf directory structure. All routes will then *work* from there. With apache this could be done with vhost configuration. Exposing the web-directory is a security risk, and should be avoided. The double `project` is probably because you installed sf in a directory `project`, and then configured a route to use `/project` in it's path.

Comment: You should read 1st the Symfony doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html , it is stated that one should use `app_dev.php` when developing.